# Trying to change the Ionic app statusbar text color

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

There appears to be a multiple of threads discussing this but not with any real solution. I was hoping it would be something straightforward. Basically, all I want to do is change the status bar text color as my header/navbar/status bar is a dark blue. The default text color is black and I just want to change it to white, it is that simple.

Where do I make these changes? I have already installed the status bar plugin and my config file is below (this is without any changes suggested in some threads).

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the status bar background, if you are using a dark background you could do this:

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
    // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
        StatusBar.styleLightContent();
});
```

I have this on the constructor of my app.component.ts

To test more options you can check the doc [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/status-bar/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alberick0. I have placed the above suggestion in the constructor of my app.component.ts and then viewed in browser has not changed, it is still black text. Or will this only take effect on device?

Comment: When dealing with native components, you should always test on the device.

Comment: I will be testing as soon as I get access (not til tomorrow morning when I have mac to run build) but right now just testing on browser.

Comment: Do you know how to change the text color to `black` on Android device?

Comment: @ErayT I was not able to do so on Ionic 4

Comment: @JosephBriggs they might have updated something. At the time of the latest version of Ionic 4, it was working for me. Go to https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar#usage and see if this will work for you. "this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');"

Comment: @ErayT ha! you are right that does work. Alas `this.statusBar.styleLightContent()` or `this.statusBar.styleDefault()` do not :/

Answer (score 5):

For black text with white background you can use below code.

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
         this.statusBar.backgroundColorByName('white');
         this.statusBar.styleDefault();
         this.splashScreen.hide();     
    });
}
```

[Check the output in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0YmH.jpg)

For white text with black background you can try following code.

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
         this.statusBar.backgroundColorByName('black');
         this.statusBar.styleLightContent()
         this.splashScreen.hide();     
    });
}
```

[Check code output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odG8e.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In `app.js` file, apply this:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      // StatusBar.styleDefault();
      StatusBar.style(1)
    }
  });
})
```

**Other options are:**

- `StatusBar.style(1)` // Light
- `StatusBar.style(2)` // Black, translucent
- `StatusBar.style(3)` // Black, opaque
- `Statusbar.styleColor`('black')
- `Statusbar.styleHex('#FF0000')` // Red

Comment: This will set the background color not the text.

Comment: Right! I modify for complete my answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To change the status bar style please refer ionic doc
    https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/status-bar/

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.splashScreen.hide();
   this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
   this.statusBar.styleDefault();
});
```

Comment: Answers that contains only code are not considered complete